# What does it mean to generate the full algebra of $SU(2)$ by commutation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, terminology, group-theory, lie-algebra

I am reading the paper 'Coherent Quantum Feedback ' by Seth Lloyd, which unfortunately is paywalled. In Section (IV. A) he states that, for a quantum system consisting of a single spin in an NMR setup, the two Hamiltonians $B \sigma_z$ and $B_x \sigma_x\text{sin}(\omega t)$ 'can be easily seen to generate the full algebra of $SU(2)$ by commutation'.

Could someone explain what this means? I know that $SU(2)$ is the group of $2 \times2$ unitary matrices with determinant 1, but have a very poor understanding of group theory and abstract algebra.  What does it mean to generate an algebra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I made a mistake in interpreting your question. Since you're only interested in knowing how to generate the full algebra this is how it is done:
To get a matrix which rotates a spinor about an axis $\hat{n}$ by angle $\phi$ we just have to calculate $$\exp\Big(i(\sigma_x \hat{n}_x+\sigma_y \hat{n}_y+\sigma_z \hat{n}_z)\frac{\phi}{2}\Big)$$

All this belongs to the representation theory of groups. I take my words back Wikipedia (though I have added the link to the *necessary sections*) won't be good for a beginner since it's filled with math jargon and you're probably new to this representation business.

Old: Everything fits in because  $su(2)$ is a lie algebra. It has finite generators but infinite elements. Every element of this set can be found by [exponentiating generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_rotation_group#Exponential_map). Though there is small subtlety of exponential sending you out of $su(2)$ to $SU(2)$.

The generators of $su(2)$ are $\sigma_x$, $\sigma_y$ and $\sigma_z$ and they are related by $$[\sigma_i, \sigma_j]=2i\epsilon_{ijk} \sigma_k$$ You know two generators using commutator find the third one and then use exponential to find any element of $su(2)$ you want. M.D.Schwartz gives a brief intro to lie algebra in chapter 10 but [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_rotation_group#A_note_on_Lie_algebra) will suffice for most basic terminology.